# Order by datetime field DESC or order by primary key DESC?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-performance

This should be a fairly regular operation: when retrieving records from a table in DB, I need them to be ordered by descending creation date time. But if I use a AUTOINCREMENT key, I can also order by descending key value.

My question is: which is better?

1. Performance-wise, I know primary keys and datatime fields use different type of indice, which one is more efficient?
2. Do they always return the same result? Does AUTO-INCREMENT key wrap around when it reaches maximum?

Comment: There are no `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields in PostgreSQL. I assume you mean `SERIAL`, which is just an `INTEGER` with a default?  Also, what makes you think they use different types of index? Both are just b-tree indexes. If it's a `PRIMARY KEY` then it'll be a `UNIQUE` index, but they're structurally the same.

Comment: @CraigRinger Does SERIAL keys wrap around? Is it something I need to worry about?

Comment: They do not wrap around. However, there is no guarantee that the ordering of rows will be the same based on timestamp vs generated key, especially if you use `current_timestamp` instead of `clock_timestamp`. If you want to order based on descending creation time, order them based on descending creation time, not by the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should identify the sorted columns clearly. If not, the order of result can be changed if you update 1 line of data